# Google Compute Firewall port 1433 blocked?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

We've been using Google Compute for a couple of years and a couple of days ago a client called in and was no longer able to access their SQL server (port 1433) based on a rule filtered by their IP address.

I even added an allow all with a priority of 0 to open all ports to the world and still port 1433 is blocked on our dev2 server and the client's server.

Port 1433 is blocked to our other servers as well, I tried to telnet with port 1433.  My IP address is open across all ports.

It's like google is blocking 1433, regardless of my firewall rules.

See screen capture if you please.

Thank you
Mike

[capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGJlk.png)

Comment: Are you able to do telne on same machine ```telnet localhost 1433```.  Check windows firewall https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13304249/firewall-port-1433-not-opening

Comment: Thanks for the replies, it was an issue on the customer side.

Comment: and a delay in the firewall rules being activated, which I'd not seen before.

Comment: Please consider answering and accepting your own question, rather than in a comment. This helps track that you found an answer.

Comment: Check windows firewall.
To enable - Refer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13304249/firewall-port-1433-not-opening

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at your screenshot and it looks good as the firewall rule “rdp2devserver” should allow all protocols and Ip addresses to access your vm “development2”. However  you can check your [Egress traffic](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls#permitted-traffic) under network analysis to see if any firewall rule is blocking your traffic.

You can also run this command **nmap -Pn [server IP] -p 1433** from your client desktop, if you see that the port is closed in the result that means that you need to open the port from your sql server.

If it is filtered that means that your server firewall is blocking the traffic.

Keep in mind that GCP is not blocking traffic on this port.